# When does Yahoo finance updates the info on the stocks?

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm not wondering when does the price of the stock gets updated. I'm wondering when does Yahoo finance updates information like p/e ratios, price estimates, gross profits, free cash flows, etc. I'm wondering about the detail information of the company's balance sheet and the likes?

Answer (score 1):

From the information I found [here](https://in.help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2310.html) it seems that Yahoo Finance updates all the data in real-time. They get the information from other sources thought, so Yahoo receives updates as soon as *the sources* upload them.

Keep in mind that some of the informations change periodically, because they are based on data that is calculated every X months, for example the p/e ratios you where asking about:

> Share prices change on a daily basis and new earnings figures are
> released every three months. As a result, a company’s P/E ratio will
> change constantly.

Source: [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/p-e-ratio-180000687.html#:%7E:text=Share%20prices%20change%20on%20a,E%20ratio%20will%20change%20constantly.)

Comment: That's what i was wondering about, at what time of the month does yahoo updates the balance sheets and p/e ratios of the companies